# Intel E7200 Windows reports each core has a different speed

Tags: cpu, intel-core2

The Control Panel app reports: E7200 @ 2.53GHz 1.90 GHz.

Seems odd to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows just displays it that way: [Name] @ [Max speed]GHz [Current Speed]GHz.

Like Sathya said, the current speed can change on the fly for power savings.

Comment: I like this answer. I have always assumed that the two figures represented a core each. But to test Louis' answer, I checked one of my quad-core machines--only two figures! So, let's presume that it is correct that the second figure represents the actual speed at this moment rather than maximum speed.

Comment: What you see in the in the System panel isn't real time. If you're really curious check out CPU-Z for speeds, and CoreTemp for how hot it's running. GPU-Z for your video card has temps, speed and more information as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Core 2 Duo E7200](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=35348&code=Intel%C2%AE%20Core%E2%84%A22%20Duo%20Processor%20E7200%20%283M%20Cache,%202.53%20GHz,%201066%20MHz%20FSB%29) comes with [SpeedStep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedStep) enabled.

> SpeedStep [...] allow(s) the clock speed of the processor to be dynamically changed (to different P-states) by software. This allows the processor to meet the instantaneous performance needs of the operation being performed, while minimizing power draw and heat dissipation. Enhanced Intel SpeedStep is sometimes abbreviated as EIST

Comment: Well, this is not a laptop. It has constant power. Even if SpeedStep were involved, why would there be two different speeds?

Comment: @user78102 whether it is laptop or not is irrelevant, all modern Intel( and AMD) processors come with dynamic frequency scaling - the rated speed (which the processor runs at during full load) and an idle speed. This is to reduce heat & power consumption